# how to put different name into a auto generated textbox so that i can put text into it using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

here is the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

Countmessage = [];

function displayCheckbox() {

$("input:checkbox").change(function() {

 message = [];

    notmessage = [];

    Countmessage.length = 0; // clear selected cb count
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        Countmessage.push($(this).attr("id"));
      }
    });

    $('input[name=message]').val(Countmessage);
  });
}
```

here is the table HTML

```
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Student's Contact No.</th>
            <th>Guardian No.</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>hehe boi</th>
            <th>Quiz</th>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Performance Task</th>
```

below is my PHP code

```
if ($resultcheck > 0){

    while($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)){

            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>".$student['fname']."</td>";

            echo '<td> <input type="text" name="number" value='.$student['scn'].'><br/> </td>';

            echo '<td> <input type="text" name="number1" value='.$student['gcn'].'><br/> </td>';

            echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='message'+i/>"."</td>";

            echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' id='Good day'/>"."</td>";
            echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' id='Quiz'/>"."</td>";
            echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' id='Test'/>"."</td>";
            echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' id='Performance Task'/>"."</td>";

            echo "<tr>";    

}
}
```

My problem here is when I check 1 checkbox it input text into all of 3rd textbox. I want that whenever I check a checkbox into row one it will input only in table row 1 textbox for message.
[image: click this picture to see what iam talking about(the data inside is all stored in db]
look at this to see what iam talking about(the data inside is all stored in db)

Comment: @ElbernieEdangalino please write code instead of posting multiple images... always  edit your javascript code in main question

Comment: i edit it @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze sorry

Comment: ok, sorry @SayedMohdAli

Comment: No need to say sorry it already looks better. Can you remove all the image links and look for proper indentation of your code.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze you can edit that for him, he is new...

Comment: still from your code, I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your selector is selecting all of the checkboxes in column 3. This bit:

```
$('input[name=message]').val(Countmessage);
```

This will select all of the checkboxes that have the name `message`, of which every row has one.

So rather just use the event target instead of a selector:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(event) {

 message = [];

    notmessage = [];

    Countmessage.length = 0; // clear selected cb count
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        Countmessage.push($(this).attr("id"));
      }
    });

    $(event.target).val(Countmessage);
  });
}
```

Comment: Well then I don't think you've shown us all your code.

Comment: here is what i think i miss 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

do i need to send how i fetch my data in my db?